# innerHTML won't print variable

Tags: javascript

Javascript - I have this code:

```
<form id="form">A: <input id="k" name="k" step=".1" type="number" value="20" width="5" /></form>

<button onclick = "calc()"> calculate </button>

<script>
function calc() {
var k = document.getElementById("k");
document.getElementById("b").innerHTML = k;
}
</script>
<p id="b"></p>
```

I get the following message when I press the `calculate` button:

```
[object HTMLInputElement]
```

Why does this not instead print my variable `k` where the HTML at the bottom is?

Comment: It's printing your variable. Your variable is a reference to the object for the HTML input element with the id of "k". Is it the value of that input element that you want to retrieve?

Comment: Before asking any question, atleast give a try to inspect why it is happening..These are very simple things...

Answer (score 3):

You want the `.value` property of the element, not the element itself.

```
var k = document.getElementById("k").value;
```

Comment: Ah, never mind, yes it does. I typed something in wrong. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Because `k` is an [HTMLInputElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement), and the toString of HTMLInputElements returns `"[object HTMLInputElement]"`. If you want to get that element's `value` then use its `value` property:

```
var k = document.getElementById("k").value;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to access the value. Right now you are accessing the whole Dom element. You need call k.value

Answer (score 1):

The function is called `getElementById()` which means it will return an element.

The `<input/>` element has a `.value` property that contains the value of the input element, so here is your code working:

```
<form id="form">A:
    <input id="k" name="k" step=".1" type="number" value="20" width="5" />
</form>

<button onclick="calc()"> calculate </button>

<script>
    function calc() {
        var k = document.getElementById("k");
        document.getElementById("b").innerHTML = k.value;
    }
</script>
<p id="b"></p>
```

Also, it's recommended to define event functions with JavaScript, to properly sepparate html from js. You can do that by using the `Element.addEventListener()` function, here is your code now:

```
<form id="form">A:
    <input id="k" name="k" step=".1" type="number" value="20" width="5" />
</form>

<button id="calcButton"> calculate </button>

<script>
    window.addEventListener("load", function() {
        var btn = document.getElementById("calcButton");
        btn.addEventListener("click", calc);
    });

    function calc() {
        var k = document.getElementById("k");
        document.getElementById("b").innerHTML = k.value;
    }
</script>
<p id="b"></p>
```

Hope this helps!